# ESP8266 AP - get typed login password

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, access-point, arduino-esp8266

I'm new to ESP8266!
I'm using NodeMCU 0.9.

When putting the device in AP mode, is there any way to get whatever the user typed when logging in (the WPA2 password to the  wifi, not a captive portal password) to the AP?

I think it ought to be possible, because  the device is getting the input from whomever is trying to log in and it needs to check out if it maches the login password, so there should be a way to get whatever he typed right?

Or do I need to dig in the firmware and change it so it'll work?

Comment: no, because you don't technically know if the user has the correct password or not. if the user connects, you can assume it's correct, but there's nothing you can tell about how "close" a non-working password is.

Comment: you want to know the password of the connected wifi network ?

Comment: yah...  is it possible even? Does the user ever send the password  to the router?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.
The way that WPA works is, the client never reveals the password to the AP, so no AP (including the ESP) can get the password just like that, unless he can find a way to break the protocol.